# making a table using div in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to make a table like this by using DIV in html & CSS[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kYpxQ.png)
but I am having a table like this [gained result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr97z.png)
I tried but could not get the desired result. where I need to change my code? can anyone help me regarding this?

```css
.tableMain {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.tableRow {
  display: table-row;
  color: aqua;
}

.tableCell,
.tableHead {
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.tableHeading {
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableMain">
  <div class="tableBody">
    <div class="tableRow">
      <div class="tableCell">
        <h2>Header-1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tableCell">
        <h2>Header-2</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tableRow">
      <div class="tableCell">
        <h2>Section-1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tableCell">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <h4>Description</h4>
        <ul>
          <li>item-1</li>
          <li>item-2</li>
          <li>item-3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tableRow">
      <div class="tableCell">
        <h2>Section-2</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tableRow">
      <div class="tableCell">
        <h2>header-1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tableCell">
        <h2>header-2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tableCell">
        <h2>header-3</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tableRow">
      <div class="tableCell">
        <p>A</p>
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        <p>B</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tableCell">
        <p>C</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tableRow">
      <div class="tableCell">
        <p>A</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tableCell">
        <p>B</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tableCell">
        <p>C</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tableRow">
      <div class="tableCell">
        <p>A</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tableCell">
        <p>B</p>
      </div>
      <div class="tableCell">
        <p>C</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: here is my CSS code
.tableMain{
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
}
.tableRow {
 display: table-row;
    color: aqua;
}
.tableCell, .tableHead {
 border: 1px solid aqua;
 display: table-cell;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
.tableHeading {
 display: table-header-group;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.tableBody {
 display: table-row-group;
}

Comment: Whay not use `<table>` element? instead of divs ?

Comment: why not just use a table? If you're displaying tabular data, then that's what tables are for. If you're trying to emulate a grid layout, don't waste your time, use one of the many existing plugins out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML structure has a few errors.. 
You see.. the last cell has a whole table in it and so should your HTML structure have a whole table inside the last cell like this:

```css
.tableMain {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.tableRow {
  display: table-row;
  color: aqua;
}

.tableCell,
.tableHead {
  border: 1px solid aqua;
  display: table-cell;
  padding-left: 5px;
}

.tableHeading {
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.tableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableMain">
  <div class="tableBody">
    <div class="tableRow">
      <div class="tableCell">
        <h2>Header-1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tableCell">
        <h2>Header-2</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tableRow">
      <div class="tableCell">
        <h2>Section-1</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tableCell">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <h4>Description</h4>
        <ul>
          <li>item-1</li>
          <li>item-2</li>
          <li>item-3</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tableRow">
      <div class="tableCell">
        <h2>Section-2</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tableRow">
        <div class="tableMain">
          <div class="tableBody">
            <div class="tableRow">
              <div class="tableCell">
                <h2>header-1</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="tableCell">
                <h2>header-2</h2>
              </div>
              <div class="tableCell">
                <h2>header-3</h2>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tableRow">
              <div class="tableCell">
                <p>A</p>
              </div>
              <div class="TableCell">
                <p>B</p>
              </div>
              <div class="tableCell">
                <p>C</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tableRow">
              <div class="tableCell">
                <p>A</p>
              </div>
              <div class="tableCell">
                <p>B</p>
              </div>
              <div class="tableCell">
                <p>C</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="tableRow">
              <div class="tableCell">
                <p>A</p>
              </div>
              <div class="tableCell">
                <p>B</p>
              </div>
              <div class="tableCell">
                <p>C</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks sir :) It worked..... Can you please explain me in simple English? coz my English is too poor :(

Comment: Your expected picture has two tables.. One parent table and one table is inside the very last cell of your main table. so you have to specify a `tableMain` class again inside the last `tableCell`. @Prem

Answer (score 0):

...this is the only drawback when using css to *fake* a table - you can't fake `colspans` and `rowspans`.

So, manually styling the exact table might be possible, but for dynamic content it wouldn't be that easy.

Actually this is why so many html elements exist - each one has its purpose. It looks like to me that the `table` is the most suitable to this case.

In case you are using divs in order to make the table responsive, you can do it the other way around - ie style table rows, table cells, etc to look like div elements when needed.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

html

```
<div class="table">
<div class="table-row">
<div class="table-cell">Header1</div>
  <div class="table-cell">Header2</div>
</div>
  <div class="table-row">
  <div class="table-cell">section1</div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      <div>title</div>
      <div>description</div>
      <ul>
      <li>item1</li>
      <li>item2</li>
      <li>item 3</li></ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="table-row">
  <div class="table-cell">Section2</div>
  <div class="table-cell">

    <div class="table">
    <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell">

      Header 1
      <div>
        A
      </div>
      <div>
      B
      </div>
      <div>
      C
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
    Header 2
       <div>
        A
      </div>
      <div>
      B
      </div>
      <div>
      C
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell">
      header 3
       <div>
        A
      </div>
      <div>
      B
      </div>
      <div>
      C
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.table
{
  display:table;
  border:1px solid;
  width:100%;
  text-transform:capitalize;
}
.table-row
{
  display:table-row;
  border:1px solid;
}
.table-cell
{
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  border:1px solid;
}
```

here is link for reference [codepen link here](https://codepen.io/chandrashekhar/pen/KqpEjj?editors=1100)